# How to properly type a structure that is amorphous but has a general shape, in order to avoid losing typeinfo and errors?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-generics

I am trying to define types as collections of shaped types using generics but am either doing something wrong or TS cannot do it. I've tried a lot of things in the past week but most of it is "lost" due to trying other things over and over. I am not sure if its possible, but my guess is, it should be. I will try to simply this as much as possible, but it will be a longer post, sorry no **TLDR** for this one.

The amount of types needed to produce a **minimal-viable-reproducible-example** for this particular issue is like 200 lines of types-only code, most of which are irrelevant but because they all chain one into another, its hard to extract a simple example from them, thus I will explain the issue at hand and post a [link to a typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBApgzgNglgOwC4FoAmcoEMBGMJgACSAngA7QDGATnGatPMsAlgLaIDmKlA9ggDcIyOPzAhgAKERII1AGZZKBAIKUkohAB4AKpAAeshGihgVAYR0BJAPIA5APo6AmgAUAogGUwAXjOXbRxcPTwA%20MABvSTAYsFIKAC4wHUkAX0lJeNV1TU8ACywKXXC-PQhDYRN-a3snNy9o2IB%20Mxz%20YrAAMjAAEXcAMSs7dx6HCxqg%20s8AbR0AXUaYpIQIIWoMrLMEEjUNMT9d3IKi8cC6kNCMmTlFZTB3Q2osFWpOUyjYsGmAawgSJKgSFoCE4cySWG2aUy5AIOjyAFcEN9DvswAAKDBQMhYJCUPJJHqYbG4vIAGgMQOerygSQelJebwAlL5wq5qLwOFAIFoISRLpI0BBKDAsNQCHwEICwAAScwcnCICBoTxIHEQHRYThJRFwACO8IIUBIbBwvBgV2QNyUBHcbHoJBsOAAVkKkJFFmAxVg0PwYCQvrL5YrlarZBrQU1tcYIPJg1DNnKTcGVWqtGFfPc7aRHS71F0wJ4MqAQNFwAAlIXw6hQOBCP1gNhYX6mPhJlZoMCAtVgXjO12mbHUDRYGAAOjANgQ9dbCvbndDBAc7N4SFLPb76igDnRcFHEHHSDyBE4wjkao7eTgnCP1DA%20Dr69zboA7nBD2BfiRTI2yGQuHFeDXRAMAEOA0HhEdPSVeFlGrZlRQIQdhzHUspE2NkIBgXhvSVFNZDTEowArfU4DFNACIpSpTFte0c1dD0Wm8cojCqRNZ1whctEQeQ5ALABGS5PhaD5PliaYAGkwEQD8-l4eR%20LmSN%20IkuZKOMUxeyfMAWgwrCcJDVNPD4lTwiSIyVI9dJPjMj0khE0Svkk6TPzkgswQLFS1KqQFgU4MAAB8wAQeETV4wLTTNCAIQCztjVNc0HJiRiLMSsAkl07DBQM-CZnEuZBNidJoQoIjoNgtMM15ckVC80wUQQDMVG2erCLRLtZDM8klD2BAkhUZkfHCQtioICtwNguUYHwNptG8PwqrMWrWh6xrmpmwj7McqSGpc%20TPHcsaYLkNMVOqy4is2PCIH6dk2EO2CoEm6aeq0cxCPMJb7rkJ7XU0Hlti67YCqSyIvlcbaZJIVzzHc8xplcVTmKo0rxuO7jeM8QG%20W0gs0qC1ZeKs2JlgJ9YRpRo7qBujkvuoH6Zte96ls2%20GId2sAYaSdHbzLKEhKIz6yuOhbeWBnHees-G1lsqW5A2GFeiJHE8S0GqkfUrYdhm1atZ61rus0PqBvCAReDA%20WSorbreGoCr5oBgX1aqeqdZajM2oXMzjYFwLgqmi2CAAVUleEcCgGg4BwAg-DRb3TfN6RLQUa0CyQG3uTmsBRfdT4TyQK6kljlkCw9TFiTxAklZJD0oFD8PaCjwv4EBU9qELuOzbQb3g9rsOI6jj0xTIEVlFpwuVkMMeKfKsIO-Ni6FfcBACgQZQQ3T8wvTT226UIu2s6BtFB6Ftvp%20OsJSQ9MgxT0rKrqUjL9KugjJG9lV04o7o6QD1P06Xlfyq7wzFoDCAhQhH0%20DQKKsh35ilpMvCEa9YEQE3tAm2ICxRgNfsXf%20iCOIby3uguk%20ZQH8k2AAWTAmgfAz4EJaGIX4TSrpWo123hAMybDsGDXRBPJAlcsTKzyN7NEBt%20B9TWitQKdI55oAtLIZOdw%20iDGGKMU4tRgheBzrEYAwBICwBkOgTAuB8AoF4SgJgBBiAwnrnQBg%20jmAIF4CgeEXIUBR3kOndAMZFQegAOSEHMDYMs7hgBDCsDoXxUZviOOfAgPxASgkhOCa4AAMhYdwkSwCImibwWJHoABCKgdDmAABJjACPYTwdks4zRpJreq0xVJExiMktJ5h3AOE8DoIp7hqnYhILfapPw-gAiBFwdy2SYkNVSGAdIC8SpqMmCEDM7MlFDBGOUiY5wGjkwZAAcVbjidBZQKgayYXmRhG4kCtUBOnDh6dvYpAoVQmhCEDkrCeNvXQS1zlukuU%20FhkCORkF4DWHqSR8mImoSg4FoK3yaC4eEShaBoW0LFMUORVo7iQuMPgLQHpM5VQ9AyUwTsNJXIzL8y%20nx6rELJY%20V0lKrmSHCJtVgbB2Hzl8sfVG1AlK0xfp8L06gbZQCUhEL4n5Rm%20QOlFEVtt0zNJqT1MVQypVcvGeI3WmgYpwmyS7QKtLDCzKvrQG2b4SBKWCqFdYnxEBviUh7O5v8xQyI9KKN4Sl9mHK%20SSsWHAUWvLFEpZFqK3k%20vQUa65V85A1kBEpHyXBGlQkTvI24BAcXQsTCCsFOrNo4ChfgOw7BoDSqTQsIVJ86kSuGf8DVIJZW8pNZW621Y1UjPraCJIVt5XNtiKIyU7a62JobVql2Sr7VIHIRAQ8vATB9WoE8EgWgnVwJdRAGRYsPV1JeEurQNarBs1kvJXkjT3Leo%20Uc222dUjTGtVHag%20UPQBrDWu0NQaIDvLPNvZNnxr68GUFALkaAIWFogMmoqEopSthzRATN%20BTAx1HMhgtuLS1gHg%20BuYjJQNoezXCla3DNpQciqOLCnA0QACIrDkNSe4ch7g7DdImEREY4wRiUcZMfJAVYGqUeCT0djPRKNZ1MJM3JDUsCmEw-h3N-AU06OSCU9wrGUnuAAGoqCYxzGwfQMPuD2UMbwyngmYoUQQKw5h%20h7K0TEVUWowC%20NkICCUsZOC%20JTdcczYArC7GIZtLEQo4CxkoOGZYIUH0pqg26MJ1gVApM6cxlTfhNrOfzp7MAAAGS%20kH%20BSkwJ4CglBgtwEoC7GOA7wTbBw8qnVmAfN%20eNdwgAhM1gdo5AvFZC%20GDI0X7j6HYMPODYHcPQq0FkVysXfMJa6T08kEq0seqSL42ulBANQF8bM8kvn1BAJSx6dlnKnPQCQKh6FvjqX9tqXZD0nw0v1XBEaVe6IsDkhwN7CVqRLsxC%20x6Sdoz07F02kCyUpHyNol8ZOuAI44AAC9-y3LFL4rjqUSP4DI7wCjiON2WW%201nakAOxRA9u7ENH%205we%20OxEB-80lmJPHx28ZHJOYiKcYAYzExiICmOYuYxURAsg2PoCgNnzAoOYCMKgLIKApNciHJoKAzOoI8eoA1YHiVFuvGW6t9bF3FdKt%2058F9H6kgwYIzq7h2Pi68OLgO4nqO8tg8xxDsZnATxkQbC8iAaKCAeNvJVxzXUZoo8SsFncUBCtBZC-VERQfmRk4xxR9rnWSuhc1MHhymEuT40MDHnq6ets8spoXdq0cfN2HCdNxLc3QabFSB9xXoe0SbB8C3xzCTgmhPLxE-PqUxTK9V4r1KyGOsLjx6lO7J2C7zjVKONLV0wAAGowB8TH4lJVlb%20-T9kLjqLsKuSYagGiB4g38CYeZIpn00AEBObAM%20G23wf46C0DZ%20lvymUAozDZxTvvOxwDtPAYrUgckN8clUCXgFxesNgQHQ8YQOIS8BXVNLFAgNgB0K5AAdSeF-F4hEl7jok3CSB0Agx-hQP6ERG1j8GfyWkIPyjRGH23SSD2W9hQLwKQAwMKAoDJk2B0D4gzCfwlSwDLRBFmUuC4IACZeD90wAcBBC-JUh%20Q%20tygT9OUSCyDCN0Q6DqR68WddFh8-8hsOVkAcQdVAR4R5B5BGg%209eNQZcCrk6lt0TVctJQ3QBDkgeCUss4tcORDQxkQRNt0g%20tpDkhxD3DAiVsvCewYDbwR13MTVJA%20sUCKxa4YA-kDAlCRE3suM4iHd0dwcEjoB4RkiOtQ4WCoBphMtsMwBFNyNTBYwVhOxeAwBWw6ARQVo79qBvgFd49ciSBEiCikAiicASiyi5hRwsBz9dFKAsAXFoA4gFZMBa5oByQSAZ0pI3R6tIiIAMhJAgA) with the code in case someone needs to take a look.

*For context, I am developing some form of Redux Extension, or Redux2.0 if you will.*

I am trying to define a type for a "return value" of a function which takes in an "array" of `Bundles` and returns a result which is based on those bundles. What is a bundle you ask? Its sort of a "Redux Plugin", something like this:

```ts
interface Bundle<
    S = any,
    Args extends object = object,
    ActionExt extends object = object
  > {
    name: string
    reducer?: Reducer<S>
    selectors?: { [key: string]: Selector }
    reactors?: { [key: string]: Reactor }
    actions?: { [key: string]: AnyAction | ThunkAction | ActionExt | ?PossibleFutureProblem? }
    priority?: number
    init?: (store: Store) => void
    args?: ArgGenerator<Args>
    middleware?: MiddlewareGenerator<ActionExt>
    persist?: string[]
  }
```

So once the function processes multiples of these bundles, it is suppose to return a BundleComposition, that looks something like this:

```ts
interface BundleComposition {
  bundleNames: string[]
  reducers: { [key: string]: Reducer }
  selectors: { [key: string]: Selector }
  reactors: { [key: string]: Reactor }
  actions: { [key: string]: AnyAction }
  initMethods: Array<(store: Store) => void>
  args: Array<{ [I in keyof any[]]: ArgGenerator<any> }[number]>
  middleware: MiddlewareGenerator[]
  processed: Bundle[]
}
```

Problem I am having is, well twofold, so lets tackle them one by one

##### 1. The Error Issue with generics/default values

When defining this function, we'd define it a function that takes in multiple `Bundles` and returns a `BundleComposition`, thus something like this would work:

```ts
type ComposeBundles = (...bundles: Bundle[]) => BundleComposition
```

Note that when defining this function, it is impossible to define what "shape" each of these bundles is, precisely, we know they must be a bundle, but `Bundle` type can, and most definitively should/will have it's type-arguments defined when creating it, however this function is used on multiple different bundles and thus we cannot define the shape of this "array" it accepts, because they are both unknown, and not the exact same shape.

Now, when we define a bundle, like such:

```ts
interface ICFG {
    tag: 'testconfig'
}

interface IActExt {
    specificTag: number
}

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    testState: 0,
}

// a simple typeguard
const isSpecificAction = (action: any): action is IActExt => !!action.specificTag

const ExampleBundle: Bundle<typeof INITIAL_STATE, { testarg: 'success' }, IActExt> = {
    name: 'testbundle',
    actions: {
        testAction: async (a, b) => { },
    },
    init: store => {
        console.log('initializing store')
        console.log(store)
    },
    args: store => {
        console.log('passing in extra args')
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions
        return {
            testarg: 'success',
        }
    },
    middleware: composition => store => next => action => {
        console.log('triggered middleware for action: ', action)
        if (isSpecificAction(action)) console.log(action.specificTag)
        else next(action)
    },
    reducer: (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type }) => {
        if (type === '@CORE/INIT')
            return {
                ...state,
                testState: state.testState + 1,
            }
        return state
    },
}
```

This is a valid bundle, there is no errors thrown by the TSC, it's generics are well defined, but it is impossible to use this bundle as argument of the previously mentioned function, when you try to do the following, an error occurs:

```ts
composeBundles(ExampleBundle)
```

**Error Message:**

```
Argument of type 'Bundle<{ testState: number; }, { testarg: "success"; }, IActExt>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Bundle<any, object, object>'.
  Types of property 'middleware' are incompatible.
    Type 'MiddlewareGenerator<IActExt> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MiddlewareGenerator<object> | undefined'.
      Type 'MiddlewareGenerator<IActExt>' is not assignable to type 'MiddlewareGenerator<object>'.
      Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'IActExt'.(2345)
```

And this error confuses me, because if you pay close attention, I am attempting to pass a **VERY DEFINED BUNDLE** into a function that expects a matching, albeit slightly different SHAPE as an argument, yet the error is saying I am doing the opposite. I read that `object is not assignable to type IActExt` where I've never assigned that, I did assign it the other way around no? What am I missing here? If a function expects a `Bundle` with a generic value equating `object` and you pass a `Bundle` with a generic of `T` where `T extends object` is that not suppose to work? The `T` is an extension of an `object` by my logic and everything I know about the whole SOLID/OOP shenanigans, this should work.

##### 2. The whole "array" is not "really an array" problem

Truth be told, what we are dealing with in the function mentioned in issue 1 is not an "array", per say. It is as we can see a spread ("...") of multiple arguments, each of which is defined as a specific `Bundle` and the order of which is very well known because we are calling a function with arguments in a specific order, thus, we are dealing with a **Tuple** not an **Array**, but there is no way to define it as such because we don't know what the arguments will be once the function is invoked, nor how many will we have.

Essentially the issue is, we have defined the types:

```ts
type T<G extends object = object> = G // for simplicity, its obviously more then this

type myObjectWrapper = {
   subObjects: T[]
}

type myFunction = (...args: T[]): myObjectWrapper 

type T1 = T<{a: string}>
type T2 = T<{b: string}>
```

And then we implement the "myFunction" and expect to get the `Result` to be related to the input values of arguments, and the type-system should be aware of this, maybe not inside the body of the function (implementation), but certainly should be aware of it as a result of invocation.

```ts
const example: myFunction = (...args) => {
  // ...implementation stuff
  return { subObjects: args }
}

const a: T1 = { a: 'some string' }
const b: T2 = { b: 'some other string' }

const myResult = example(a, b) // doesn't work properly, type information is lost
```

So what is a proper pattern for defining these functions that accept an "array" of values, be it as an argument spread or an array if that makes it better somehow, where each value must be of some type `T<G>` but the types of `G` are different. This function returns an object wrapped around the values taken. How do we write this properly?

Because I find using a simple `T[]` doesn't work, yet I cannot specify a `G` because that could be anything that extends an object, which also forces me to define a "default" for the value `G` so I just default to `object`, but then I get errors from "issue 1" above.

Comment: Your first problem is contravariance in parameters of functions. See [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-covariance-contravariance/).

Comment: I read the article, thank you, but I do not get how would I change this, I mean the function expects in general "any kind of bundle", I am passing it a more "specific" version of one such bundle with it's type arguments defined more strictly. One of those influences a function inside the bundle, thus the contravariance messes with me, but what should I do, what is the proper solution?

Comment: What is even worse is, MiddlewareGenerator seems to be problematic, but ArgsGenerator is not, both of them are functions, both of which are extended in the more specific bundles, what the hell with that?

Comment: (link)[https://tsplay.dev/w2538W] the problem with your code is that you have default values for your generic everywhere. If you want to infer the correct type you have to pass your generic to your types

Comment: I will need to look into this more and if its applicable, thanks for now @Filly, Ill get back to these comments in the following days. The way I see it is, without default values, TS forces me to define the generic whenever I use a type, it doesn't infer it, this is why I make defaults so that I can write types like T WITHOUT the <G> next to it. Because when I define types as T<G> then whenever I use them, it asks me to also supply a generic. For example with Promise, you can't just write Promise, you have to specify Promise<type>, ill get back to this in the following days

Comment: You can get a lot of insight from looking at the source code and types of `@reduxjs/toolkit`.  Specifically on the `createSlice` function.  For example, rather than defining the `actions` as union, they would infer the type of the entire `actions` object apply that type as one of the generics on the `Bundle`.

Comment: I will look into that, because I am stuck at the very end of this thing and it is getting too complex to ask questions, like every question is a wall of text with 300 lines of code, its just not doable that way anymore. Next step for me would be to try to hire someone with super-deep knowledge like to untangle this with me, I don't know. I almost got everything working, it comes down to fixing 1 more function signature and its done, but I can't get it right

Comment: I wrote you a long answer and I did play around a little with your types, but I don't actually understand how the bundles get combined and there might be some issues with circular typing.  For example the `BundleComposition` would ideally depend on the types of its specific `Bundle` elements, but each `Bundle` has a `middleware` property which depends on the entire `BundleComposition`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am in the middle of some really hoop jumping coding now, its been like 20 hours and my head is fried, so I will look at it with fresh eyes after I get some sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start by talking about the examples in your **2. The whole "array" is not "really an array" problem** section.

```
type T<G extends object = object> = G // for simplicity, its obviously more then this

type myObjectWrapper = {
   subObjects: T[]
}
```

The `myObjectWrapper` type **must** be a generic type.  Otherwise, `subObjects` will have type `T<object>[]` always, in all circumstances, regardless of the arguments of `myFunction`.

@Filly is right that you have far too many default values on your generics.  But you're not properly understanding how inference works.

> The way I see it is, without default values, TS forces me to define the generic whenever I use a type, it doesn't infer it, this is why I make defaults so that I can write types like T WITHOUT the  next to it. Because when I define types as T then whenever I use them, it asks me to also supply a generic.

There is nothing which can be inferred in `type myObjectWrapper` because there are no generics.  It is **always** `{ subObjects: T<object>[] }`.

The way to make use of type inference is to define strongly-typed functions, where the generic type parameters (`T` and `G`) are passed between the various arguments and return types of the function.  The inference comes into play when you go to *use* the function.  You will not have to specify any generics when calling the function because they can be inferred from the arguments.

`T` is a higher-order type that modifies another type `G`.  Therefore `myFunction` needs to know what `G` it is modifying.  I think understood that a little bit in your linked playground, where you made `myFunction` a generic which depends on `G`.

```
type myFunction = <G extends T[]>(...args: G) => myObjectWrapper
```

But you've got some fundamental contradictions, as `G extends T[]` means that `G` is an array of `T` objects but `type T<G extends object = object> = G` means that that `T` equals `G`.  That's impossible.

So let's lay out some assumptions: I'll say that `myFunction` is a generic which depends on type `G`.  Its argument is an array whose elements have varying types and the generic type parameter `G` describes the type of this tuple.  The function returns a wrapped object where the `subObjects` is an array containing a modified version of each of your input objects.

TypeScript [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) can applied to tuples and arrays [since v3.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html).  We need to use a mapped type to describe the transformation of `...args: G` to `subObjects: T<G>`.

When I define the types, I do not have default values anywhere.  Every generic needs to be passed around in the implementation.

```
// Mapped type to transform the tuple.
type T<G> = {
    [K in keyof G]: G[K] & { added: string }
}

// Return type of the function.
interface myObjectWrapper<G> {
  subObjects: T<G>
}

// The function depends on the type of its input tuple G.
type myFunction = <G extends object[]>(...args: G) => myObjectWrapper<G>

const example: myFunction = (...args) => {
  // We need an assertion because array.map doesn't understand that its a tuple.
  return { subObjects: args.map(g => ({ ...g, added: 'added' })) as any }
}
```

But you don't need any types when you *use* the function.  Your types `T1` and `T2` can go.  All we do is call the function with variables `a` and `b`.

```
const a = { a: 'some string' }
const b = { b: 'some other string' }

const myResult = example(a, b)
```

This is where type inference comes into play.  Our function is well-typed so the `myResult` variable gets the correct inferred type:

```
const myResult: myObjectWrapper<[{ a: string; }, { b: string; }]>
```

Which means that each `subObject` has the correct, very specific type.

```
// No errors.
console.log(myResult.subObjects[0].a)
console.log(myResult.subObjects[1].b)

// Errors, as expected, when accesing types on the wrong array element.
console.log(myResult.subObjects[0].b)
console.log(myResult.subObjects[1].a)
```

---

I've already written a novel and I haven't gotten into your Redux types.  But hopefully I've explained some of the fundamentals.  Here's some general advice:

- Remove all default values from your types to force yourself to pass around the known generics.  You need the state type `S` in one place to match the `S` in another place.
- In some places you can use a single generic to refer to a vary complex type which itself contains a bunch of generics.  Nothing is lost here, as the new type represents the entirety of the complex type.  For example:

```
const composeBundles = <B extends Bundle<any, any, any>[]>(...bundles: B): BundleComposition<B> => {
```

- When using this sort of logic, you can define types to work backwards to extract internal types from a complex type.  You are already doing this with `StateFromReducersCollection` and `ReducerFromReducerCollection`.
- Try using keyed dictionary objects instead of tuples.  I find it a lot easier to keep the correct types and to know what you are accessing.
- Look at the source code and the types for the `@reduxjs/toolkit` package as they've already dealt with a lot of the issues that you are dealing with here.  Their `createSlice` function creates a "slice" object which is similar to your "bundle".  It contains a strongly-typed reducer and a dictionary of strongly-typed action creator functions.
- Read Lenz's article [Do not create union types with Redux Action Types. It's most likely an antipattern.](https://phryneas.de/redux-typescript-no-discriminating-union) which explains why Redux Toolkit instead uses type guard functions to associate the payload type with an action.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and all the links to resources. I need to study this more. On the bright side, I got everything to actually work, I've solved it.... but it's not good enough, since I did not forsee that inference will not work how I imagined, even though its working, generic "objects" are what I have now in most places, so I will need to rewrite it from scratch :( If you have the time/will I'd appreciate if we could talk/review what I have ATM before I scrape it and make v2.